# Use Div Click Event As UpdatePanel's Trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a div as an Image button, as the ASP Imagebutton was causing a flash on click, no matter what.

The Div click raises a server side event to bind the grid and it works good. Just that the whole page loads. In order not to, I tried to have it as a trigger.

Now, it gives the error -

> 'div1 being reistered through RegisterAsyncPostBackControl or
>   RegisterPostBackControl must implement either
>   InamingContainer,IpostBackDataHandler, or IpostbackEventHandler'

**ASPX:**

```
<div id="div1" runat="server" class="search"></div>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" updatemode="conditional">
<Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="divSearch" EventName="Click"/>
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
  <asp:gridview....../>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**C#:**

```
public partial class Home: System.Web.UI.Page, IPostBackEventHandler
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       div1.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.
                                  GetPostBackEventReference(this, "div1_Click");
     }

    protected void div1_Click()
     {
       bindGrid();
     }

    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArgument))
      {
        if (eventArgument == "div1_Click")
          {
            div1_Click();
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Any way to make this work?

Comment: the error says it all: "*InamingContainer,IpostBackDataHandler, or IpostbackEventHandler*". Try an `asp:panel` instead.

Comment: No . same thing. Did it work for you?

Comment: This is because the div tag doesn't support the PostBack event.

Comment: So what can be used then if a div tag doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can add inside the update pannel an asp button, this button with css property display = none and with jquery on div click, trigger the asp button click.

```
 <div id="jqmCollapsibleDiv" data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePannel1">
                <ContentTemplate>
                     <%-- Update pannel content --%>
                <div style="display: none">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTrigger" OnClick="btnTrigger_Click" />
                </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

jquery code

> ```
>         $("#jqmCollapsibleDiv").collapsible({
>             expand: function (event, ui) {
>                 $("#btnTrigger").click();
>             }
>         });
> ```

If you dont use jquery mobile collapsible and use simple html div, add a tabindex to a div, and use a click event:

```
$('#simpleHtmlDiv').click(function (){
   $("#btnTrigger").click();
});
```